# Why sometimes assigments in R are by reference?

Tags: r, pass-by-reference

Sometimes when I work with R and I want to make a copy of a variable to keep it as is, and use it later to monitor changes, R does not copy the variable and all changes are applied to both of them.

Why does this happen? How to prevent it? What part of following image is wrong?

[image: ad]

But not all the time:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I added the image.

Comment: Looks like you are using the `data.table` option here (`:=`)

Comment: Uses a package which's main feature is to avoid copies, complains that it doesn't copy ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `copy`ing of the objects.  If you don't make a `copy`, then it would change at the same memory location.  To avoid that, we can `copy` the object and this would prevent it from any changes to get updated while the second object changes

```
library(data.table)
b <- copy(a)
```

A reproducible example would be

```
a <- as.data.table(mtcars)
b <- a
b[, v1 := 2]
identical(a, b) # a also changed 
#[1] TRUE
```

If we do `copy`

```
a <- as.data.table(mtcars)
b <- copy(a)
b[, v1 := 2]
identical(a, b)
#[1] FALSE
```

Also, according to `?copy`

> A copy() may be required when doing dt_names = names(DT). Due to R's copy-on-modify, dt_names still points to the same location in memory as names(DT). Therefore modifying DT by reference now, say by adding a new column, dt_names will also get updated. To avoid this, one has to explicitly copy: dt_names <- copy(names(DT)).

---

If we do the assignment with `<-`, the memory location changes after the change

```
a <- 2
b <- a
tracemem(a)
#[1] "<0x7fcedcafc370>"
tracemem(b)
#[1] "<0x7fcedcafc370>"
a <- a + 2
tracemem(a)  # change here
#[1] "<0x7fcedcaa3ba0>"
```

Comment: I added another image. Why it did not happened in that case then? are they different?

Comment: @NoLie  In the second case, you are doing `<-` and it is to a different memory location.

Comment: So, the problem is `:=` inside the last line of the first image where it says: `biofix := 666` ?

Comment: @NoLie  I updated the post with an example, you can check with `tracemem` to find whether the object is getting updated in the same location or not